# Gulp Less Errors

Tags: javascript, gulp, less

For some reason my gulp file has stopped outputting errors - 
regarless of what i ad to my less file it builds and displays my 'less worked' message - 
I'm pulling my hair out!  ANy ideas please?

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
var less = require('gulp-less');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var notify = require('gulp-notify');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var liveReload  = require('gulp-livereload');
var path = require('path');
var moment = require('moment')

gulp.task('less', function () {
  return gulp.src('./_dev/less/styles.less')
    .pipe(less({
      paths: [ path.join(__dirname, 'less', 'includes') ]
    }))
.pipe(less().on('error', function(err){
    gutil.log(err);
    this.emit('end');
}))
.pipe(liveReload())
.pipe(gulp.dest('./_dev/css'))
.pipe(notify('Less worked at (' + moment().format('MMM Do h:mm:ss A') + ')'));
});
```

Comment: And what about .. the actual errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error handler is not part of the main chain of `pipe()` calls, so execution always continues to the final pipe to `gulp-notify`. Error handling in Gulp can be tricky, as the following overview shows:

[Error management in gulp](https://gist.github.com/floatdrop/8269868)

To handle this correctly you should use [gulp-plumber](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-plumber) to handle errors, e.g.:

**Gulpfile.js**

```
'use strict'

const gulp = require('gulp')
const $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')()
const del = require('del')

// ------------------------------------------------------------

gulp.task('clean', done => {
  del([ './out/**' ]).then(paths => {
    done()
  })
})

// ------------------------------------------------------------

gulp.task('less', [ 'clean' ], function () {
  return gulp.src('./*.less')
    .pipe($.plumber({
      errorHandler (err) {
        $.notify.onError('Error: <%= error.message %>')(err)
        this.emit('end')
      }
    }))
    .pipe($.less())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./out'))
    .pipe($.notify('Finished: <%= file.relative %>'))
})

// ------------------------------------------------------------

gulp.task('default', [ 'less' ])
```

**ok.less**

```
@col: #05f;
div {
  font-size: 12pt;
  a {
    color: @col;
  }
}
```

**bad.less**

```
@col: #05f;
div {
  font-size: 12pt;
  a {
    color: @link-col;
  }
}
```

Given the two input files `ok.less` and `bad.less`, the `less` task will show an error for `bad.less` and the finished message for `ok.less`, with the end result being a single output file `out/ok.css`.

By commenting out the line `this.emit('end')` in the `errorHandler` function, the `less` task will instead show the error message for `bad.less`, and then stop all further processing - you will end up with no output files at all.

Does that help you? It should work in the general case for any errors in your pipeline, allowing you to stop all further items in the pipeline if you so choose.